# Why do C# and VB.NET implicitly marshal char* differently?

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, string, marshalling

So I have a function, written in C++, that looks like this...

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall SomeFunction(char *theData)
{
    // stuff
}
```

... and I'm using it in my current project (written in C#). There are other projects that use this function written in VB, looking like this:

```
Public Declare Function SomeFunction Lib "MyDLL.dll" _
    Alias "_SomeFunction@4" (ByVal theData As String) As Integer
```

So I tried writing an equivalent in C#, but found that using the string type didn't actually work for me - the string would come back with the same data I passed it in with. I tried using `"ref string"` instead to pass the string by reference and I got a memory access violation.

After doing some digging, I found that this was the correct implementation in C#:

```
[DllImport("MyDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "_SomeFunction@4")]
public static extern int SomeFunction(StringBuilder theData);
```

Now I know that VB.NET and C# are quite different, but I suppose I always assumed that strings were strings. If one language can marshal `char*` to `String` implicitly, why can't the other, requiring a different class altogether?

(edited the title for clarity)

Comment: It might be interesting to take a look at both versions with JustDecompile or .NET Reflector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Now I know that VB.NET and C# are quite different, but I suppose I always assumed that strings were strings

Strings are [immutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwcx436.aspx) in .net.  Ask yourself why it is that `ByVal` passing of an immutable data type can result in the value changing. That doesn't happen for normal functions, just for `Declare`.

I'd guess it all has to do with maintaining some backwards compatibility with `Declare` statements from classic VB6 which were done this way. To my mind the black sheep here is the VB.net code rather than the C# code.

Comment: Also, only `Declare` does this. `<DllImport()>` does not (VB does do funny things with ByRef parameters to allow you to pass in properties and constants, but this isn't one of them)

Comment: +1. This is absolutely **for backwards compatibility** with the VB6 `Declare` statement. In new VB.Net code you might prefer `<DllImport()>`. In their wisdom, the VB6 designers decided `ByVal As String` in a VB6 `Declare` would be equivalent to a C `char *`. Behind the scenes the VB6 runtime creates a copy of the original Unicode string in "ANSI" format according to the current Windows code page, and passes the address of the copy to the DLL. For completeness, here is [the original Microsoft VB6 documentation](http://vb.mvps.org/tips/vb5dll.asp) on integrating DLLs with VB6.

Answer (score 3):

Because they are different languages.  VB.NET can a great deal of things that C# cannot for many reasons.  I don't see the problem to be honest.

I should add you could have simply did **ref char[]** and it would have worked.  One problem I see is that your calling conventions do not match.

So that also is likely the reason you got a memory exception error.

Comment: Calling conventions are fine, `stdcall` in all code above. AV is because `ref string` simply does not match with `char*`. Have to use `StringBuilder` in C# for that. There's no way that native code can construct a valid .net String object.

Answer (score 0):

Since string is immutable to begin with, I'm guessing that VB somehow wizards the call to allow for the buffer to be modified by the function. Perhaps internally VB is actually passing a StringBuilder as well.

I wouldn't be surprised if this was a design call by the VB team to make API calls more VB6-like.