# Calling C++ dll class from Visual Basic

Tags: c++, vb.net, class, dll

So me and my friends have this project where I have a C++ class that needs to be called from Visual Basic. I've seen a few things about this but not much has helped. Does anybody know how to do this? I have a lot of experience in C++ but none in Visual Basic. My friends are the VB experts.

I am using visual studio but I also have gcc/g++ if that will be needed.

Comment: This has been discussed more than once, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632713/how-to-call-a-c-dll-file-from-visual-basic-2010

Comment: Calling a c++ dll yes. But I haven't found an answer for c++ CLASS dll.

Comment: Generally C++ *is* classes.  Otherwise it would be (mostly) just C.

Comment: Well the link you posted and what I've found online only deals with functions, not classes.

Answer (score 1):

Comments are too crowded.  You did not say what particular problem you are having (perhaps getting a class instance). Here are some promising links:

- [Importing Class from C++ dll](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=322905)
- [Thread: How to call a C++ dll function at runtime ?](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?514943-How-to-call-a-C-dll-function-at-runtime)
- [Calling DLL Functions from Visual Basic Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dt232c9t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Calling a C++ DLL from Visual Basic](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4c486d10-fe8b-49da-a5f1-8054b82251ff/calling-a-c-dll-from-visual-basic?forum=Vsexpressvb)

Since VB.Net is managed, and C++ is not, there is some work which may be needed for *marshalling* the data to/from the DLL (see the 4th link).  The first link deals with classes as requested.  Functions of course cannot be disregarded, unless you are interested only in passing objects around.  Some of this also is dealt with on SO:

- [Why do C# and VB.NET implicitly marshal char* differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744975/why-do-c-sharp-and-vb-net-implicitly-marshal-char-differently)
- [return string from c++ function to VB .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049478/return-string-from-c-function-to-vb-net)